# Country name with space not accepted in BlackBerry ObjectChoiceField

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am developing a registration page in BlackBerry app. I am sending all the fields entered to the local server.Country is one of the form fields and is in a ObjectChoiceField. Whenever user selects a country having more than one word for ex: United States of America, it says sign up failed. When user selects country with single name, registration is always successful.Can anybody guide me how can I make the ObjectChoiceField accept the spaces or remove the spaces in the country?

Comment: I think that is your coding problem.print the values which you are sending to server whether correctly passing or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem in ObjectChoiceField. For example if you want to send the Value like "Black Berry" you must send it to the web service like **"Black%20Berry"**. Because %20 takes the space character. So after you are taking the value form ObjectChoiceField means......

ar[obchfield.getSelectedIndex()];// this is your value say for example:"Black Berry".

Take this below code in seperate Classname Utility.java:

```
public class Utility {
public static String escapeHTML(String s){
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int n = s.length();
       for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
          char c = s.charAt(i);
          switch (c) {
             case ' ': sb.append("%20"); break;
             default:  sb.append(c); break;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}}
```

Then do like this:

```
Utility.escapeHTML(ar[obchfield.getSelectedIndex()]);//converts the "Black Berry" to "Black%20Berry".
```

then it returns a String like: "Black%20Berry" and send it to server. Enough.
Your problem is solved.

If you have any doubt come on StackOverFlow chat room name "**Life for Blackberry**" to clarify Your and our doubts.

Comment: creating a new string and calling above function to my URL then establishing connection solved my problem :)